# THREE js, on before render function.

Tags: javascript, three.js, render

I'm making some enemies and I want all of them to update their position before render.

I could make an update() function, but i've tryed to make onBeforeRender() fucntion attached to all of them.

The problem is that nothing happens.

Here is my code, i don't know where it fails.

```
var i = 0; 
for(i =0; i < num_enemics; i++ ){
    //CLONE THE ENEMY FROM THE PROTOTYPE
    var enemic = dolent.clone(true);
    enemic.name = i.toString();
    enemic.visible = true; 

    //SPAWNS ON RENDER POSITION
    enemic.position.x = Math.random() *(40) - 20; 
    enemic.position.y = 0.7; 
    enemic.position.z = Math.random() * (28) - 14;

    self.veloicity = new THREE.Vector3(0.1,0,0);
    //FUNCTION TO BE CALLED BEFORE RENEDER
    enemic.onBeforeRender(function(){
        self.position.addVectors(self.position,self.velocity);
    });

    scene.add(enemic);
}
```

Comment: You haven't defined self anywhere

Comment: it's an object function, isn't self referencing to itself?

Comment: self is not a pre-defined value in javascript. Can you post the entire closure that this code is contained in? If so I will try to help you.

Comment: oh yeah, i just changed self for this, btw, the function onBeforeRender is not called. (i putted a console.log inside, and nothing shows).

Comment: does `dolent` have an onBeforeRender method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the pattern to follow when defining `onBeforeRender`:

```
object.onBeforeRender = function( renderer, scene, camera, geometry, material, group ) {

    // your code here
    this.position.add( this.velocity );

};
```

Comment: Thanks will try now